# How do I find the full path to a file?

Tags: paths

I'm running into a little bit of bother with finding the path of a file called `oragi` I tried the `find` command but it didn't help.

I'm following the instructions on this page if it is of any help. :) https://github.com/neurobin/oraji

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please sum up shortly the linked information so that people who want to help don't have to read more than your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ubuntu comes with a very handy indexation of its contents. Simply type:

```
locate oragi
```

Do note this indexation is based on a database that is automatically updated, this means that very recent files won't be found by the *locate* command. Normally this is not a big issue, but if you need the database to be immediately updated you can type:

```
sudo updatedb
```

Cheers! :)

Comment: You might also want to mention that this does not work for newly created files as this is based of from a database that needs to be updated.

Comment: Truly, worth mentioning for sure, thanks! Although the database is updated oftenly enough... Anyway, executing "sudo updatedb" does the trick at any time.

Answer (score 3):

Well if you have installed it correctly , then follow the command

```
whereis oraji
```

This will display where it is installed.

**Additional info:** 
 if you have used the following commands as given in your link to install oraji :

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:neurobin/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oraji
```

The above commands add the ppa to your system and on issuing cmd **sudo apt-get install oraji** it will install it like a software. But this doesn't seems to be a software more like a script packaged to install oracle. So probably it will be installing the java in your system. So after installing oraji , in the terminal type command as follows :

```
java --version
```

If everything went fine , you will see java version installed.